# Selecting nodes stored separately regarding the same information

Tags: xml, xpath, basex

I'll try to explain with a MWE. Here we have 9467328.xml:

```
<GROUP year="2004" groupid="9467328">
<TOWN name="Springfield"></TOWN>
<PEOPLE>
<PERSON eyecolor="brown" fullname="Jane Doe">
<HEALTH>
<WEIGHT>67</WEIGHT>
<HEIGHT>1.75</HEIGHT>
</HEALTH>
</PERSON>
</PEOPLE>
</GROUP>
```

And this is 9467328_extended.xml:

```
<GROUP source="SGXML" date="28092004">
<PEOPLE>
<PERSON fullname="Jane Doe">
<MEALS>
<MEAL id="1" title="Breakfast"/>
<MEAL id="2" title="Lunch"/>
<MEAL id="3" title="Dinner"/>
</MEALS>
</PERSON>
</PEOPLE>
</GROUP>
```

These are matching files, each with different information about the same group. One of them has the `groupid` tag, but not the other. **Both filenames contain the `groupid` value, across the database**.

I'm able to select all the `PERSON` nodes from a specific `TOWN`:

`/GROUP[TOWN/@name="Springfield"]/PEOPLE/PERSON`

Or count all the meals eaten:

`count(/GROUP/PEOPLE/PERSON/MEALS/MEAL)`

I need to count all the meals eaten in a certain town, but the values are empty because they are in fact different nodes:

`/GROUP[TOWN/@name="Springfield"]/count(/PEOPLE/PERSON/MEALS)`

I got stuck after finding out how to strip the filenames down to the `groupid`:

`replace(fn:base-uri(),'^(.*/)(.*?)\.\w+$','$2')`

**How would you rewrite the expression so that the `MEALS` node can be accessed based on the `groupid` value?**

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: But there is no `TOWN` in your extended xml though. How can you expect meals eaten in that town ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I'm running arch linux, basex 8.6.4

Comment: @svasa, you're right, the extended database doesn't include `TOWN` information and this is THE problem, but I'm just working on a downloaded database (simplified and translated for this question). Each `TOWN` has a unique `groupid`, hence I mentioned the filename. There can be two `TOWN` nodes with the same name, even if they have distinct `groupid`. Will rephrase question.